# Get all posts of categories with just subcategories relations from GraphQL request

Tags: graphql, contentful, gatsby

Have a simple model like **post** / **category** / **subcategory** with relation between *posts <-> subcategories* & *categories <-> subcategories*.

Questions are :

- How to make the GraphQL request with the `gatsby-source-contentful`
  plugin in order to get all post in category page (without adding a
  relation field between posts & categories ?
- Is it the Contentful right way for having post classification in a 2 levels tree ?

Seems to be enable by Contentful API as said in this post : https://www.contentful.com/blog/2015/02/17/content-trees-tags-and-facets-in-contentful/

Thx for replies

```
{
  contentfulCategory(id: {eq: $id}) {
    id
    title
    post <- ?
    subcategories {
        slug
        title
        post {
            id
            title
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe a way to do that is something close to :

```
{
  contentfulCategory(id: {eq: $id}) {
    id
    title
    subcategories {
        slug
        title
    }
  }
  allContentfulPost(filter to category ?) {
   edges {
    node {
     slug
     title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I'd be interested in the answer